# Problem with jQuery and $.ajax when trying to parse JSONP

Tags: jquery, jsonp

So, here's my JSONP URL:

http://community.tradeking.com/leaderboard.js

And here's the jQuery I'm trying to parse it with:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  url: 'http://community.tradeking.com/leaderboard.js?callback=?',
  success: function () {
    alert("something");
  },
});
```

And here's the error I'm getting in Firebug:

> processLeaderboard is not defined

I've also tried getJSON and the jQuery JSONP specific plugin, but they all fail in similar ways. The JSONP is being used successfully elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked just fine for me in jsbin using chrome.

```
var processLeaderboard = function(x) {
  alert(x[0].member.avatar.public_filename);
};

$(document).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonp: 'processLeaderboard',
     url: 'http://community.tradeking.com/leaderboard.js?callback=?'

   });
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a function that is called `processLeaderboard`, since that function name seems hardcoded into the response from your link.

```
var processLeaderboard = function (data) {
  alert('Do your stuff here');
}

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'processLeaderboard',
  url: 'http://community.tradeking.com/leaderboard.js?callback=?',
  success: function () {
    alert("something");
  },
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting "processLeaderboard is not defined".

Comment: Use jsonpCallback: 'processLeaderboard' instead of jsonp: 'processLeaderboard'